# Fixed center alignment

Tags: android

I need to achieve fixed central alignment, like this in the picture:

http://postimage.org/image/t735us1z3/

So the flag images are always in the center while the two TextViews are growing to the left and right. So no matter how long the text is going to be the images will still be in the center. And plus the "vs" TextView in the middle.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
 >

<TextView android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
         />



     <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/flag1"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"   
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" 
        android:src="@drawable/bayern25"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_item_entry_title"
        />

       <TextView android:text="-"
             android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/flag1"
         />


       <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/flag2"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"  
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"  
          android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
        android:src="@drawable/wolfsburg25"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text"
        />


     <TextView android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/list_item_entry_title"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/list_item_entry_title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/flag2"
         />
```

Comment: attachment is vulnurable . can't understand where are two textviews , where is vs textView.

Comment: The VS text view is between the flags. The order is TextView1, Flag1, VS TextView, Flag2, TextView2

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/846/aaaaaaaaaaal.png/

Comment: I did try with LinearLayout also, and making   android:gravity="center_horizontal"  but if one of the Textviews is bigger then the other, the other gets pusshed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a RelativeLayout, you only need to position the "vs" TextView in the center using layout_centerInParent attribute (android:layout_centerInParent="true") and then position the other components relative to that one. your code would look like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_title"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/flag1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/flag1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bayern25" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/text"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/flag1"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="-"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag2"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text"
        android:src="@drawable/wolfsburg25" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/list_item_entry_title"
        android:layout_below="@id/list_item_entry_title"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/flag2"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using LinearLayout weight and gravity, something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:width="match_parent"
    android:height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:width="0dp"
        android:weight="1"
        android:height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Team 1" />
    <TextView
        android:width="wrap_content"
        android:height="wrap_content"
        android:text="VS" />
    <TextView
        android:width="0dp"
        android:weight="1"
        android:height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Team 2" />
</LinearLayout>
```